# Jquery horizontal scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I was trying to get this working, found here: [Horizontal scrolling div using buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561124/horizontal-scrolling-div-using-buttons)

But i was getting a error; unexpected token in my code, i can't figure out what i'm missing.

```
      $('#left-button').click(function {
         $('#productcontainer').animate(
           marginLeft: +="200px"
           , "fast");
      });
```

Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try fixing your code like this:

**JQUERY**

```
$('#left-button').click(function() {
    $('#productcontainer').animate({
        marginLeft : "+=200px"
    }, "fast");
});
```

*Note the adjustments on your code!*

check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/Wa66q/)!

Comment: Thank you for you're nice answer! Makes now a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at what you linked to, you will see that you are missing the `{}` for the animate method.

```
.animate({ parma1, param2, etc })
```

Comment: Zuul's answer is more complete.