# Horizontal scroller not scrolling

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm probably missing something really simple but I just can't get this to work! I've based it on this question - [Horizontal scrolling div using buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561124/horizontal-scrolling-div-using-buttons)

It doesn't scroll left or right.

I've also got this error:

[image]

Also when the links are clicked the page reloads/jumps, is there a way to fix that?

```
                <div id="imgThumbs" class="scroller" style="height:97px;width: 306px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap;">
                    <a href="#" id="left-button">Left</a>  
                    <a href="#" id="right-button">Right</a>
                    <div id="contentScroller">                         
                    <?php $counter = 1; while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>                     
                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none!IMPORTANT;color:white!IMPORTANT;" class="showImg">
                            <img class="image-<?php echo $counter; ?>" src="<?php echo the_sub_field('image'); ?>" width="90" height="68" alt="<?php echo the_title(); ?> <?php echo $counter; ?>" />
                        </a>
                    <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <script>
                jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                        $('#right-button').click(function {
                            $('#contentScroller').animate({
                            marginLeft: -="306px"
                            }, "fast");
                        });
                        $('#left-button').click(function {
                            $('#contentScroller').animate({
                            marginLeft: +="306px"
                            }, "fast");
                        });                     
                    });
                    </script>
```

### UPDATE

I just found something else... you're able to keep scrolling left and right even when the content ends. So if there's 6 images in there, it shows the first 3, click right, shows the next 3, click right and it scrolls to an empty area, click again and so on. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: But what is the problem and where?

Comment: @Lion Sorry, updated, it's not scrolling left or right when clicking the buttons.

Comment: In your click handler, `function {` should be `function() {`. That will solve the error you are seeing.

Comment: @AndrewR I'm now getting the same error but with `-=`

Comment: `marginLeft: -="305px"` is incorrect. The -= needs to go inside the quotes. `marginLeft:"-=305pc"`

Comment: @AndrewR Brilliant. Like I said I'd taken this from the link in my question so they hadn't fixed the errors in an accepted answer. Do you want to post an answer for me to accept?

Comment: Good deal, those pesky syntax bugs will get you every time. One misplaced character and the entire thing breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your click handler, `function {` should be `function() {`.

`marginLeft: -="305px"` is incorrect. The -= needs to go inside the quotes. `marginLeft:"-=305px"`

**UPDATE**

I didn't test this, but basically what you need to do is make sure that you are not at the end of the left or right before doing the animation. You may need to make some modifications to this for your application, but it should give you the basic idea.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#right-button').click(function() {
        if($('#contentScroller').css('marginLeft') > 0){
            $('#contentScroller').animate({
                marginLeft: "-=306px"
                }, "fast");
             });
         }

    $('#left-button').click(function() {
         if($('#contentScroller').css('marginLeft') < -1 * $('#contentScroller').width()){
            $('#contentScroller').animate({
                marginLeft: "+=306px"
                }, "fast");
            });                     
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: I just found something else... you're able to keep scrolling left and right even when the content ends. So if there's 6 images in there, it shows the first 3, click right, shows the next 3, click right and it scrolls to an empty area, click again and so on. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Hmm, just tried the update, it doesn't seem to scroll left/right now.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't test it. You may need to do a `parseInt($('#contentScroller').css('marginLeft'))`