# How do I accomplish a sliding transition effect for HTML text elements?

Tags: jquery, css

I am looking to create an HTML page where `<p>` tags can be interacted with based on mouse clicks. I am looking to incorporate horizontal-sliding transitions with ease-in/ease-out, like those in [deck.js](http://imakewebthings.com/deck.js/introduction/) or [timeline.js](http://timeline.verite.co/) for some of these `<p>` tags.

Beyond digging in the deck.js and timeline.js code (which has been pretty fruitless thus far), can someone recommend a tutorial or example for accomplishing this effect for text? My google-fu has only pointed me to very specific examples for image slide decks.

Comment: Wanna give us an update or choose a correct answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this question could help you out [Sliding divs horizontally with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864305/sliding-divs-horizontally-with-jquery) 
.Remember that `<p>` tags can be moved as `div` so I think you won't have issues. If I'm wrong, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

put it in a div and then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    $("div").animate({
      right:'250px',
    });
  });
});
```

or whatever way you want to move it
you can look up all the effects at w3schools

http://w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp

Comment: No programming hipster. The site posted makes a good point on why not using w3schools. Please look ar it. You might desagree of course

Comment: Well I disagree. For a beginners programming supplement and a general source of low-level reference, it's better than any other site.