# HTML Scroll Hortizontal

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a new website for my dad, everything is going fine so far, I have used this Stackoverflow tutorial to create a page that I want to change the content of with a hyperlink, and make it scroll horizontal: [Sliding divs horizontally with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864305/sliding-divs-horizontally-with-jquery/24476555#24476555)

I have managed to get it all working on my website, apart from one small detail which I really want fixed, and I was hoping that somebody here could help me with that :)

If you open this page: http://dev.joopvanleeuwen.nl/, you can see that the part *© 2014 Schoorsteenveegbedrijf Joop van Leeuwen* has in it stays nice on the bottom of the page, under the text, like it is supposed to.

But on this page, http://dev.joopvanleeuwen.nl/online-afspreken/ it just stops right under the 3 button hyperlinks, but I want it to stop under the page content.

The reason it is fixed it because the program we use needs a Iframe, that also has a set height in order to prevent that the customers need to scroll, we had problems before that people could't find the next button.

I have tried fixing the content height at 700px with !important using the style tag only on that page, but that didn't work.

Could somebody please help me with this?

Thank you,

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height on `#afspraak-content`.

```
#afspraak-content {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0 5px 0 0;
width: 100%;
/* height: 650px; */
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

The content height at 700px is fine as-is (although you can remove the !important declaration if you clear the height from `#afspraak-content`). You just had height defined in two content areas.