# How to detect the end of a horizontal scroll in a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to implement a horizontal scroll inside a div. My question is how can I detect the end of the horizontal scroll?

I tried something like this

```
$(function() {
var scrollLeftPrev=0;
$('#scrollquestion').scroll( function() {
  var newScrollLeft=$('#scrollquestion').scrollLeft();
  if(scrollLeftPrev===newScrollLeft){
    alert('right end');
  }
  if(newScrollLeft===0){
    alert('left end');
  }
  console.log($('#scrollquestion').width());
  console.log(newScrollLeft);
  scrollLeftPrev=newScrollLeft;
 });
});
```

left end alert works, since it will become 0 for all the device sizes. For right end, it depends on the device size.

Screen :
[image: Horizontal scroll]

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/arunslb123/trxe4n3u/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `scrollWidth` and `width` along with your `leftscrollwidth` to get the difference. In your case there is offset of `8` so it will give the difference of `8` it may be because of your padding or margin.

```
var $elem=$('#scrollquestion');
var newScrollLeft = $elem.scrollLeft(),
    width=$elem.width(),
    scrollWidth=$elem.get(0).scrollWidth;
var offset=8;
if (scrollWidth- newScrollLeft-width==offset) {
    alert('right end');
}
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/trxe4n3u/2/)

Use the [outerWidth()](http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth) to get the offset including the width like,

```
var $elem=$('#scrollquestion');
var newScrollLeft = $elem.scrollLeft(),
    width=$elem.outerWidth(),
    scrollWidth=$elem.get(0).scrollWidth;
if (scrollWidth-newScrollLeft==width) {
    alert('right end');
}
```

[Another Demo without using offset](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/trxe4n3u/4/)

Comment: can you tell me how offset is calculated as 8 here? EDIT : Thanks. Got it, it's because of padding is set as 4px.

Comment: the offset is the padding left and right
but you can do it without the offset as below (posted as an answer)

Comment: In my case, I had to apply Math.ceil() under width, as it was different from `scrollWidth-newScrollLeft` by 0.1 px.

Answer (score 10):

Try http://jsfiddle.net/trxe4n3u/3/

```
$(function() {
    $('#scrollquestion').scroll( function() {
        var $width = $('#scrollquestion').outerWidth()
        var $scrollWidth = $('#scrollquestion')[0].scrollWidth; 
        var $scrollLeft = $('#scrollquestion').scrollLeft();

        if ($scrollWidth - $width === $scrollLeft){
            alert('right end');
        }
        if ($scrollLeft===0){
            alert('left end');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried your code. left end works, but right end is not working.

Comment: @ArunPrakash change scrollLeft with `var scrollLeft = Math.round($('#scrollquestion').scrollLeft());`

Comment: @ArunPrakash you need to remove the decimal, change that line : if (~~($scrollWidth - $width) === ~~$scrollLeft)

Answer (score 2):

Rohan kumar's answer is correct and works fine, but you can do this without calculating the offset manually

```
var newScrollLeft=$('#scrollquestion').scrollLeft();
      var divWidth = $('#scrollquestion').outerWidth();
      var scrollwidth =$('#scrollquestion').get(0).scrollWidth;
      if(newScrollLeft === scrollwidth - divWidth){
        alert('right end');
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

For my specific case, dangor's solution with the

```
if ($scrollWidth - $width === $scrollLeft) {
        alert('right end');
}
```

did not work for me because calculating ($scrollWidth - $width) created a very small decimal that made the left-side of the comparison a float, and the right-side ($scrollLeft), an integer. Changing it to the code below works perfect for me.

```
if (parseInt($scrollWidth - $width) === parseInt($scrollLeft)) {
            alert('right end');
}
```

Comment: Correctly answered!