# Best approach to hide an absolutely positioned <div> when horizontally scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have an example of my current work here: https://jsfiddle.net/pv5xroLc/

My problem is that when the table in my example is fully scrolled to the right, the faded gradient still covers part of my table even though it cannot be scrolled further, thus it makes the last column harder to read. I am wondering what the best solution to hiding this gradient is while still making it clear that the table can be scrolled horizontally (this is going to appear on mobile).

Currently, my html structure is as follows:

```
<div class="fader">
    <div class="scrollable">
       *content*
    </div>
</div>
```

The `.fader` element has an `::after` pseudo-element which contains the "fader" on it, which is an absolutely positioned element with the linear-gradient I'm using to indicate that the element can be scrolled horizontally. The `.scrollable` element is a horizontally scrolling element that holds my table.

---

I currently have two solutions I have considered:

1. Add a listener to check when the scrollbar has reached the right side [(like this example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068664/how-to-detect-the-end-of-a-horizontal-scroll-in-a-div), then hide or fade out the gradient. The problem with this is that I have more than one of these faded tables on the page, and I'm not sure what the most effective way to setup these listeners would be. I'm using Vue.js with this, so I'm not sure if this could/should be a directive or just a listener set on the page for each of these tables.
2. Add some blank space to the right of the table, so you could scroll a little bit past the end of the actual table and the gradient would just blend into the background. I've tried adding padding and margins to both the table and the `.scrollable` element but it does not add any extra space after the table.

If anyone has suggestions for what they think I should do, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Listener fires only when event occurs, so it won't lead to bad performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I needed to implement this functionality, I would make a Vue component that would take in the table content (or any content) in a `slot` and then listen to the scroll event of the `.scrollable` div, adding or removing the faded `::after` content if the div was scrolled all the way to the right.

Here's an example:

```
Vue.component('fader', {
  template: `
    <div class="fader" :class="{ 'scrolled-right': isScrolledRight }">
      <div class="scrollable" ref="scrollable">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      isScrolledRight: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onScroll(event) {
      this.updateIsScrolledRight(event.target);
    },
    updateIsScrolledRight({ scrollLeft, offsetWidth, scrollWidth }) {
      this.isScrolledRight = (scrollLeft + offsetWidth) === scrollWidth;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.scrollable.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
    this.updateIsScrolledRight(this.$refs.scrollable);
  },
  destroyed() {
    this.$refs.scrollable.removeEventListeneer('scroll', this.onScroll);
  }
})
```

```
.fader.scrolled-right::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Here's how the component works:

- A `ref` property is added to the `.scrollable` div so that it can be easily referenced in the component's script.
- An `onScroll` method is attached to the scroll event of the `scrollable` ref when the component is `mounted` and removed when the component is `destroyed`.
- The `onScroll` method calls an `updateIsScrolledRight` method, passing it the scroll event's `target` (the `.scrollable` div).
- The `updateIsScrolledRight` method looks at the `scrollLeft`, `offsetWidth`, and `scrollWidth` properties of the element passed as the parameter to determine if the element is scrolled all the way to the right and sets an `isScrolledRight` property to `true` if so and `false` if not.
- The root div of the component has a bound `:class` attribute which will add the `scrolled-right` class to the div if the value of `isScrolledRight` is `true`.
- The `.scrolled-right` class sets the div's `::after` content to have `opacity: 0;`.
- The `updateIsScrolledRight` method is also called in the `mounted` hook so that, if the content in the `<slot>` happens to not be wide enough to need a scrollbar, the fade will be removed in that case as well.

---

Here's a full working example:

```js
Vue.component('fader', {
  template: `
    <div class="fader" :class="{ 'scrolled-right': isScrolledRight }">
      <div class="scrollable" ref="scrollable">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      isScrolledRight: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onScroll(event) { 
      this.updateIsScrolledRight(event.target);
    },
    updateIsScrolledRight({ scrollLeft, offsetWidth, scrollWidth }) {
      this.isScrolledRight = (scrollLeft + offsetWidth) === scrollWidth;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.scrollable.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
    this.updateIsScrolledRight(this.$refs.scrollable);
  },
  destroyed() {
    this.$refs.scrollable.removeEventListeneer('scroll', this.onScroll);
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
})
```

```css
.fader {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: 46px;
}

.fader::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: 15px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), white);
  width: 10%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

.fader .scrollable {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
  
.fader.scrolled-right::after {
  opacity: 0;
}

.breakdown-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 8px auto;
}

table {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table thead {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #da291c;
}

table thead th {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}

table thead th:first-of-type {
  width: 120px;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

table thead th:last-of-type {
  width: 80px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}

table tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #fce9e8;
}

table tbody td {
  width: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
 
table tbody td:first-of-type {
  width: 120px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

table tbody td:last-of-type {
  width: 80px;
  padding-right: 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <fader>
    <div class="breakdown-title">Total Revenue Bonus</div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Oct</th>
          <th>Nov</th>
          <th>Dec</th>
          <th>Jan</th>
          <th>Feb</th>
          <th>Mar</th>
          <th>Apr</th>
          <th>May</th>
          <th>Jun</th>
          <th>Jul</th>
          <th>Aug</th>
          <th>Sep</th>
          <th>Year End</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>YTD Target</td>
          <td>$1,325,705</td>
          <td>$2,651,410</td>
          <td>$3,977,115</td>
          <td>$5,302,821</td>
          <td>$6,628,526</td>
          <td>$7,954,231</td>
          <td>$9,279,936</td>
          <td>$10,605,642</td>
          <td>$11,931,347</td>
          <td>$13,257,052</td>
          <td>$14,582,757</td>
          <td>$15,908,463</td>
          <td>$15,908,463</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>YTD Actual</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
          <td>$19,956</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>% to Target</td>
          <td>2%</td>
          <td>1%</td>
          <td>1%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
          <td>0%</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </fader>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah this makes a lot of sense. I didn't know you could do `{ scrollLeft, offsetWidth, scrollWidth }` as parameters when taking an object, so thanks for that btw. I prefer just setting up listeners instead of adding an extra div for padding which was what I was considering. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

(I'd rather comment on the OP than answer, but it won't let me start a comment yet because I'm too new so apologies for that.)

I've dealt with stuff like this before, and my quick hack following your #2 solution idea above would be to add another `<th>` after `<th>Year End</th>`, then style that with the appropriate width to match the gradient fade. You could then decide whether to also put in blank `<td>`s below it.

ALSO I noticed that your white gradient has a pretty solid white line where it starts (right above "$9") - you can smooth that out in line 15/16 of your SCSS by adding more reference points (it took me a while to figure this out back in the day, just including in case it's helpful):

`background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), white);`

`width: 30%;`

---

1. Current hard line to white:

[image: current with hard line]

2. Softer transition to white:

[image: softer transition line]

Comment: I like the linear-gradient suggestion, I'll switch to using more reference points because I definitely noticed that white line but figured it wasn't too big of a deal. Didn't know it would be an easy fix like that. I thought about putting another element after the table and forcing them to be next to each other with `display:flex`, which I may end up doing. I don't know if adding a th will be a quick fix for my solution though, since I have other tables with a different structure that need to have widths that line up (3 cells from this table will line up with 1 from quarterly). Thanks though.